# How to pass comma separated value in attribute when input parameter is enum in c#

Tags: c#, .net, enums, attributes

I have one custom attribute like below,

```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class SetValForAll : Attribute
    {
        public string Limit { get; set; }

        public SetValForAll(string limit)
        {
            Limit = limit;
        }
    }
```

While using this attribute(SetValForAll) I want to pass the value of **limit** using one Enum, not one single value but comma separated value of the enum.

My Enum is like below,

```
public enum LimitEnum
{
    Initiated,
    InProcess,
    Done
}
```

If I apply the attribute in any type I am expecting comma separated value of enum like "Initiated,InProcess" will be received in the attribute

I tried below piece of code but it is showing error. How I can use the enum in attribute level to pass comma separated value?

```
[SetValForAll(nameof(LimitEnum.Initiated, LimitEnum.InProcess))]
public class UsingTheAttributeHere
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a Flags enum.  eg

```
[Flags]
public enum LimitEnum
{
    Initiated = 1,
    InProcess = 2,
    Done = 4
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SetValForAll : Attribute
{
    public LimitEnum Limit { get; set; }

    public SetValForAll(LimitEnum limit)
    {
        Limit = limit;
    }
}

[SetValForAll(LimitEnum.Initiated | LimitEnum.InProcess)]
public class UsingTheAttributeHere
{
}
```

Comment: You must set the enum values explicitly to 1,2,4,8.  If you allow dev=0, then dev | qa = qa since `0 | 1 == 1`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a string in your attribute, you can use string interpolation.

```
[SetValForAll($"{nameof(LimitEnum.Initiated)},{nameof(LimitEnum.InProcess)}")]
```

But if the receiving end is going to read these as enum values anyway, you are better off using a `Flags` enum and passing an OR'ed value to the attribute, like in David Browne's answer.